# Посоветуйте дистрибутив Linux

Tags: debian, linux

Посоветуйте дистрибутив Linux, наиболее подходящий для web разработчика и системного администратора.

Мне советуют смотреть в сторону Debian, т.к. опыт работы с Linux у меня уже есть.

Answer (score 4):

При выборе дистрибутива для новичка имеют значение такие вещи как:

1. Наличие мощного сообщества,
2. Наличие разнообразной документации,
3. Простота и удобство интерфейса,
4. Отличная работа при настройках по умолчанию

Было время, когда среди Linux лидировал RedHat, сейчас его место во многом занимает Canonical. Его дистрибутив Ubuntu по факту сейчас наиболее популярен и удовлетворяет всем перечисленным выше признакам. Его и стоит выбирать.

Выбор между Debian и Ubuntu некритичен, это практически одно и то же.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле для ваших целей подойдет любой дистрибутив Linux, не отяжеленный неповоротливыми DE, ненужными модулями в ядре или другой *nix, например, FreeBSD...Используйте то, к чему душа лежит

Answer (score 1):

Если есть опыт, д. б. и предпочтения, а нет, так появятся в процессе работы. Берите любой доступный Вам и подходящий по критериям, которые привёли John Brown и alienrom, ставьте LiveCD, на VM или винт и проверяйте на соответствие Вашим предпочтениям, целям и задачам. ИМХО, наверное любой дистрибутив можно допилить до нужного состояния, вопрос в том сколько времени и сил это займёт конкретно у Вас.

Answer (score 1):

Если для web-разработчика и сисадмина могу порекомедовать OpenSuse.Критерии по которым она мне подошла:

1. Программы -Linux он и в африке linux, большинство программ работают одинаково прекрасно на всех версия, есть большое Но с пакетами, у меня сложилось впечатление, что rpm достать легче чем deb. Очко в пользу OpenSuse, ее пакетный менеджер zypper работает на rpm.
2. Конфигурирование - трушные линуксоводы будут колотить себя пятками в грудь и кричать, что Yast(отличная конфигурационная утилита от OpenSuse) это не правильно, это как в винде и т. д. Я же скажу каждому свое: боевому серверу - консоль, десктопу kde или gnome. Yast это то что не достает многим дистрибутивам linux, почему такое не сделали в бубунте, несмотря на свалившиеся ей на голову многомиллионные инвестиции - непонятно. Марк Шатлворк знает ответ)). И все же - консоль никто в OpenSuse не отменял, гибкость не теряется.
3. Документация - возможно сообщество в бубунте действительно велико, только вот с доками я не увидел там ничего хорошего(возможно поэтому и выросло сообщество), взгляните на документацию OpenSuse, там исчерпывающе описывается как теория так и практика решения конкретной сисадминской задачи. И опять же доки: большинство инфы берется из первоисточников, например, man страницы, а они есть всегда и везде в независимости от дистра.

Answer (score 0):

Самый лучший Debian - это Kubuntu.

Comment: это шутка?!Или вы на полном серьёзе?

Answer (score 0):

Если в Оракле будешь БД мутить, никакая бубунта не поканает, см. список его рекомендуемых ОС в КвикИнсталлГайде

Answer (score 0):

fedora, будет самый свежий софт без подключения каких-либо репозиториев, сразу из коробки. да и сообщество поможет, есть jabber-конференция fedora@conference.jabber.ru

Answer (score 0):

Для системного администратора, имхо, самый лучший выбор - это FreeBSD. Самое главное - исчерпывающий хэндбук, где можно найти 90% ответов на вопросы касаемо настройки + немалое количество тематических ресурсов. ПО практически такое же как на линуксе - после FreeBSD  без труда разберетесь и в настройке иксов в убунту, и настроите cron в каком-нибудь линуксовом роутере. В иксовых визардах происходит конфигурирование все тех же старых добрых текстовых конфигов, только при нажатии кнопки "Готово" не всегда происходит корректное сохранение. После того как вы вдоволь накопаетесь в этих конфигах ручками найти и исправить ошибки после иксовых визардов вам не составит труда.    FREEBSD НЕ самая лучшая ОС в мире, но после нее вы сможете легко ориентироваться в ЛЮБОМ никсовом дистрибутиве. Так что если вы хотите стать не просто еще одним пользователем линукса, но системным администратором, то FreeBSD - это путь настоящего джедая.

Comment: to sergarcada: ну раз спрашивают про дистрибутив linux надо советовать linux я советую openSUSE (вот кстати и мануал по установке http://freeproger.ru/index.php/programmy/76-opensuseinstall)

Answer (score 0):

"Самое главное - исчерпывающий хэндбук, где можно найти 90% ответов на вопросы касаемо настройки"Максимум процентов 5 там может и есть.

"FREEBSD НЕ самая лучшая ОС в мире"Она самая лучшая.